# 500 (Internal Server Error) received after opening category - Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

Today I have updated to Magento 2.3.2, everything works correctly except the categories. When I try to access a category I receive a 500 error in the browser console and a blank page with a single phrase:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it? Execute the following orders without success:

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: you need to check server error log for the actual error that you are facing

Comment: I have Ubuntu + Nginx, what file I need to check? because in the Nginx files I do not have any information

Comment: it's probably in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: first make it empy by `> /var/log/nginx/error.log` then open your browser to get just your error, then open `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: no new errors appear in this file

Comment: turn on the developer mode and check if you are getting any error on browser `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation`

Comment: the same, not new information in this file  :(

Comment: no, this time you wont get information in file, after developer mode, clean cache and check on browser, developer mode will show you error on browser

Comment: I was in development mode because it is my development environment

Comment: sometimes error are appeared but are not visible due to css. check your error in view source of browser `ctrl + u` error would be at the bottom of page source

Comment: I have updated my question with two new pictures

Comment: strange... in developer mode error should appear here... please confirm you are in developer mode or in default mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: I have updated my question with a new photo

Comment: That's weird.. just one last thing :) please check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`

Comment: if you have custom theme, make sure you have it upgraded as well

Comment: I have to execute some command? Because the author of the theme that I bought does not support me...

Answer (score 1):

Open app/boostrap.php

Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

And Run following commands...

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php -dmemory_limit=56G bin/magento deploy:mode:developer -s
php -dmemory_limit=56G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=56G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```